# networkmanager script failing, how to see full logs output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, logging, systemd

`journalctl -u NetworkManager.service` tells me `dispatcher: 01-ifupdown [...] /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01-ifupdown exited with error status 1`

This is almost certainly a script we have hooked/symlinked in `/etc/network/if-up.d/our-hook`, **however** all such scripts run without error when run directly.

Where can I find, or how can I enable, a full capture of `stdout`/`stderr` for all things network manager runs (narrowing verbosity to `if-up.d` is obviously fine, too).  Insight into the vernacular relating to this answer would be helpful, too - I'm sure this information exists but my search-foo is coming up short.

`ubuntu server 18.04`

the script in questions begins with the following.  On the test device, `/bin/sh` symlinks to `dash`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -xue
echo "[...] $(date)"
```

Comment: If it is a shell script `set -x` would make the script output be in logs, wouldn't it?

Comment: i'm doing that, and have added the head of the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it turns out it's **NOT** `NetworkManager.service` that would have the relevant logs:

a different service, `NetworkManager-dispatcher.service`, is what runs scripts in `/etc/network/if-*.d/*` - and the `journalctl` for that service does in fact have all `stdout`/`stderr` from the operation.

And for the curious, the underlying error was an `exec format error` from `run-parts`; the script we have generating the hooks had an extra newline i had not noticed:

```
# --> extra newline here, before ~shebang
#!/bin/sh
...
```